# Android: Navigation Drawer symbol doesn't appear

Tags: android

I'm trying to program a Navigation Drawer Panel, but I don't know why the hamburguer symbol doesn't appear. I've already read lots of similar posts here but I can't find the solution.
The code I have is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
(...)
```

and I'm doing the following imports:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: try this toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_hamburger);

Comment: @ConstantinCerberus, didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Actually What I've done in mine is that I removed the action bar which led to the same case as yours which is the missing hamburger icon.
If taken positively, this led a better way to customize the icon as you want it to. Just use an `ImageView` in `app_bar_home`.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/toggle"                        
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_for_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/iV1"            
        />
```

and Copy this in your MainActivity.java/ NavigationDrawer.java

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV1);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            }
        });
```

Now, this View will work as a navigation bar toggle. 
And the best thing is you can use custom made icon or get the icon from the internet.
By the way don't forget to adjust the `ImageView` to place it right where you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I face a problem similar to yours. In my case i simply add this line of code:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

hope solve your issue.